# How to blend the border of the imageview with the background?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a situation here. I am creating a movie review app and I am stuck with the below mentioned problem. Please look at the image below. The bottom border of the poster at the top of the layout is clearly visible. I am trying to blend the border of the poster with the gradient of the background. How can I achieve this? Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.DetailActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moviePoster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="100dp"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/black_gradient" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playTrailer"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="playTrailer"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_trailer" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/favorite"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="@string/movie_title" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="markFavorite"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_favorite"
            android:tag="@string/unfavorite" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favoriteLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="@string/rating" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dateLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/favoriteLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/favoriteLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_release_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/releaseDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="@string/release_date" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateLayout"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                tools:text="@string/overview" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="@string/review"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/reviewList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/moviePosterFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/black_gradient">   <---- set as foreground

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moviePoster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</FrameLayout>
```

black_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#46000000"
        android:centerY="70%"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: After trying your answer. Still the border is visible. I tried playing with the `centerY` and opacity of the `centerColor` but didnt workout.

Answer (score -3):

Onload=confirm(document.domain)>” Local File inclusion (LFI), or simply File Inclusion, refers to an inclusion attack through which an attacker can trick the web application in including files on the web server by exploiting functionality that dynamically includes local files or scripts. The consequence of a successful LFI attack includes Directory Traversal and Information Disclosure as well as Remote Code Execution. Typically, Local File Inclusion (LFI) occurs, when an application gets the path to the file that has to be included as an input without treating it as untrusted input. This would allow a local file to be supplied to the include statement.